# Fails to setup docker for port number 6006 published for TensorBoard

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I am following the step to setup docker for tensorflow on Windows 10.
 https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#2
But in this step, it just hangs there, I don't get the prompt back.

```
docker run -it --publish 6006:6006   --volume C:\users\johnd\tf_files:/tf_files --workdir /tf_files tensorflow/tensorflow:1.1.0 bash
```

Can you please tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Facing the same issue. Kindly share if you have been able to fix it. Thank you!